# Couldnt understand the Array behavior in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

i was writing code to append new email to an empty array in my Rails App. like this:

```
@users_email = Array.new 
@users_email << User.find_by_id(@comment.user_id).email 
@users_email << User.find_by_id(Comment.find_by_id(@parent_id).user_id).email if !@parent_id.nil?
```

**Note:** Here `@comment` is just a hash of `id, user_id, parent_id` and `@parent_id` is a the id of a Parent of any Comment. as in Hierarchy of Parent-child.

But instead of having two items in array ex: `["ak@xyz.com", "aks@xyz.com"]` I am getting only one item ex:`["aks@xyz.com"]` after appending second item.

My confusion starts when I try to save above expression in an Instance variable and tries to append the same into an empty array, It behaves as expected.
Ex:

```
@users_email = Array.new
@first = User.find_by_id(@comment.user_id).email
@second = User.find_by_id(Comment.find_by_id(@parent_id).user_id).email if !@parent_id.nil?

@users_email << @first  # ["ak@xyz.com"]
@users_email << @second  # ["ak@xyz.com", "aks@xyz.com"]
```

where as this wasn't the case in previous one.
Can someone please explain whats happening here.

## Update

By mistake I have place `"="` instead of `"<<"` while appending first element to the array for the first case and after appending second one I got the result something like `"ak@xyz.comaks@xyz.com"` but for some reason in my Rails Application I was getting only the first email id in return.ex: `["ak@xyz.com"]`

So, probably this question is now not relevant to the issue raised. Sorry for bugging all of you.

Comment: In your last code block you've got `@user_email = Array.new`, `@users_email << @first` and `@user_email << @second`. Was that a typo in the `@users_email << @first` part? (there's an _s_ in there, which isn't on the other two lines). Also, in Ruby you usually write `[]` over `Array.new`. So, instead of `@user_email = Array.new` you would have `@user_email = []`.

Comment: Ohh yeah I thats a typo

Comment: Ok, so was the content of `@comment.user_id` the same in both cases?

Comment: Yes its the same in both case..infact both the use case are having exact input just the change in writing code

Comment: are you sure you got `["aks@xyz.com"]` instead of `["ak@xyz.com"]` when you were expecting `["ak@xyz.com", "aks@xyz.com"]`?

Comment: then try using `+` operator to check if it works in your case http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-2B

Comment: I think i made a mistake, will update on Question.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have this check `!@parent_id.nil?` at the end of the following statement:

```
 @users_email << User.find_by_id(Comment.find_by_id(@parent_id).user_id).email if !@parent_id.nil?
```

In the first case, `@parent_id` apparently is `nil`, so the statement never executes: hence only one value is appended to the array.

Aside: prefer [using the array literal syntax](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#literal-array-hash) (`ary = []` over `ary = Array.new`)

Comment: That line is also in his second code block. There are some typos in that code block though (as I mentioned in my comment on his post).

Comment: I realize that, but, like I said, in the first case, `@parent_id` must have been `nil` while in the second case it wasn't. I'm fairly certain the behavior you're seeing is just a coincidence since the behavior of the two blocks is nearly identical aside from the additional instance variables.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, but he got `["aks@xyz.com"]` in his first try. That's from that second line, the line that you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: Also, using [] over Array.new doesn't affect the behavior if i am not wrong

Comment: No it doesn't. It's just poor style. Regarding your code, it ***must*** have been nil or `@second` had to have been defined before. It's impossible for the return of that line (`User.find_by ... if !@parent_id.nil?`) to differ otherwise.

Comment: exactly but its happening as I am just storing the same return value in variable and its working